# New-ADUser + OtherAttributes w/ Splatting for Readability

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
foreach ($Person in $People) {
    $NewUserParams = @{
        Name = $Person.Name
        Server = 'xxxx.com:389'
        Path = 'CN=Users,CN=addressBook,DC=xxxx,DC=com'
        Credential = $Credentials
        givenName = $Person.givenName
        otherAttributes = @{sn=$Person.sn}
    }
    New-ADUser @NewUserParams 
}
```

I have many additional attributes (otherAttributes) that I would like to add that are available to me in the formart New-ADUser -Name XXX -OtherAttributes @{sn=xxx} .   However, I am trying to using splatting to make the OtherAttributes more readable, along with other required parameters.  I don't need to using splatting for the entire command, my goal was to break up otherAttributes so it wasn't a long string that wrapped.  Ideas?

Comment: The value of `otherAttributes` is a hashtable. You can wrap it the same way you're wrapping the `$NewUserParams` hashtable.

Comment: Can you give me an example?  I have tried to do it a couple different ways and failed.  I tried the following with no success 

otherAttributes = @{
sn=$Person.sn
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `otherAttributes` is just another hashtable, and can be wrapped like any other hashtable:

```
$NewUserParams = @{
    'Name'            = $Person.Name
    'Server'          = 'server.example.com:389'
    'Path'            = 'cn=Users,cn=addressBook,dc=example,dc=com'
    'Credential'      = $Credentials
    'givenName'       = $Person.givenName
    'otherAttributes' = @{
        'sn' = $Person.sn
    }
}
```

Personally, I recommend putting the keys of the hashtables in quotes to avoid surprises, but at least in the above example that's not required.

If the above doesn't work for you you need to provide more details about the code you're running and the error(s) you're getting. Displaying the content of the generated hashtable inside the loop usually helps troubleshooting problems with particular values.

Comment: I am getting the following error: 
New-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'OtherAttributes'. The argument is null or an element of the
argument collection contains a null value.
At line:12 char:12
+ New-ADUser @NewUserParams
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser

Comment: As a parameter in the New-ADUser the  Otherattributes is not set equal to a hash table, perhaps that is related?  I have no problems executing the above command without the otherAttirbutes parameter or if I don't do spatting and set the -otherAttributes @{sn=$Person}.

Comment: @JGillTech Given your code it's clearly not possible that the value of `OtherAttributes` is null, so did you verify that none of the values of the nested hashtable are null? Also, please edit your question if you need to provide addional information. Code and errors in comments are unreadable.

Comment: Yes, none of the other values are null.   I will update the question with what I have tried and the result... what works and what does not.

Comment: Thanks, I found the error when I was updating the question.  I forgot to include the -Properties * when getting the user objects from AD :)