# Powershell New-ADUser to AD Issue

Tags: powershell

I am studying Windows server and am new to powershell scripting. I am trying to add AD user through power shell but am getting error.
This is my script

```
new-aduser
-name "Elizabeth Andersen"
-SameAccount "eander"
-GivenName "Elizabeth"
-Surname "Anderson"
-Path 'OU=Research,DC=adatum,dc=local'
-Enable $true
-AccountPassword "Pa$$w0rd"
-ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
```

Is there anything wrong with this script?
Thank you for the help

Comment: Could you post the error message you are getting. It would help us to help you :)

Comment: Besides what @hsimah answers about the password, your code is totally broken. You cannot simply put newlines between the parameters without at least using backticks to denote the line continues there. Way better would be to use splatting for all these parameters and use their correct names. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55306316/9898643) for instance.

Comment: Yes i thought so that is was broken but this is the example provided in the textbook.new-ADUser-Name “Elizabeth Andersen”-SamAccountName “eander”-GivenName “Elizabeth”-SurName “Andersen”–path 'OU=Research,DC=adatum,dc=local'-Enabled $true-AccountPassword “Pa$$w0rd”-ChangePasswordAtLogon $true  (Course, 2017-12-05, p. 41)

Course, M. A.  (2017-12-05).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a read of the documentation for this cmdlet. [You can find it here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/new-aduser).

An account password is not set using a simple string, it requires a `SecureString`. I would get familiar with secure strings as they come up a lot in PowerShell. You can use `ConvertTo-SecureString` to generate them.

I would also double check all your parameter names as I can see `Enable` is incorrect - it should be `Enabled`.

Comment: THank you very much. i obviously have along way to go with powershell. I will do abit more reading on the new-ADUser.

Comment: Not a problem. Just remember to include error messages in future posts - makes it much easier to get help :)